# Set default selected item in select input using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-i18n

I'm using vue-i18n to handle translations in my software. I'm trying to create a select input to change between languages. To do so, I'm using the following code:

```html
<select class="form-control" v-model="$i18n.locale">
  <option v-for="(key,value) in languages" v-bind:key="value" :value="value">
    {{key}}
  </option>
</select>
```

I want that my actual language ($i18n.locale) appears as selected in my select input. However, none of the languages is selected, as the following image shows. How can I solve this? [image]

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ [vue-i18n](http://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/).

Answer (score 3):

First argument in `v-for` is the `value` and second is the `key`.

[Documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html).

So this should work:

```
<option v-for="(value, key) in languages" :key="key" :value="value">
```

You have [an example](http://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/locale.html) in `i18n`'s docs.

---

Or, since you want to use the values as keys (as they're unique & primitives):

```
<option v-for="lang in languages" :key="lang" :value="lang">
```